# Unable to drag/drop Table View Cell under Table View

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am having trouble dragging and dropping table view cell under a table view. 
Trying to follow http://shrikar.com/swift-ios-tutorial-uisearchbar-and-uisearchbardelegate/ to create a functional UISearchBar but I am getting Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value due to this issue.

Any clue on what could be happening?

[image]

First edit:
I opened the xib file in source code mode and moved the tableViewCell component under TableView. But this does not get reflected on xib interface builder.

Comment: What happens when you drag Cell under TableView (above Search Bar) in the Document Outline Sidebar

Comment: Are you designing this interface in a storyboard or via a xib?

Comment: This is being done via xib. Xcode is not letting me drag the cell just under TableView (above Search Bar). It just gets back to where it was.